Base change for finding fibers of the pushforward of a line bundle along a proper non-flat morphism
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper morphism whose fibers have different dimensions, in particular $f$ is not flat. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. What conditions would be sufficient to be able to conclude that the fiber of $R^i f_* L$ at $y \in Y$ is $H^i(f^{-1}(y),L|_{f^{-1}(y)})$? (If possible, this would be desirable to have for fibers at all $y \in Y$).
